# Why does this cast to DATETIME2 contain extra granularity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to cast the following `DATETIME` to `DATETIME2`:

```sql
DECLARE @x DATETIME = '2021-12-10 19:58:41.333'
SELECT CAST(@x AS DATETIME2)
```

The result is `2021-12-10 19:58:41.3333333`. Why does the cast add 0.0003333s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what some understand, `datetime` is not accurate to 1/1000th of a second, it is accurate to **1/300th** of a second. This is why the last digit of a `datetime` is always `0`, `3`, or `7`, as they represent 0/300th, 1/300th and 2/300th respectively of a second (3/300th would be `0` again).

For `datetime2`, however, the datatype can have a precision of `0` - `7`. `0` meaning accurate to 1 second, and `7` being 100 nanoseconds or 1/10 microseconds.

When you convert a `datetime` to a `datetime2` the fact that `datetime` is only accurate to 1/300th of a second is reflected in the converted value (Note that for older versions of SQL Server this is not true) and so will show the 1/300th to a the new degree of accuracy.

Let's take the value you have `2021-12-10 19:58:41.333`. Here the `.333` is infinite, it's more `.3333333333~`. This is because you can't represent 1/3rd (or 1/300th) accurately with a base 10 number. You then convert (`CAST`) your value to a `datetime2`. You omit the precision, so this defaults to a precision of `7`. This gives you `2021-12-10T19:58:41.3333333`, as the 1/300th is now displayed up to a precision of 7 (note that the above is accurate to 100 nanoseconds, *not* 100/3 nanoseconds).

Had you had a time like `2021-12-10 19:58:41.357` and converted it to a `datetime2(4)` you would have got `2021-12-10 19:58:41.3567`. If you were to then convert that to a `datetime2(7)` you would get `2021-12-10 19:58:41.3567000` as the "1/300th-ness" accuracy was lost when it was converted to a `datetime2(4)`.

*As alluded to, in older versions of SQL Server ([2014 or prior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15#SQL15)) the above is not true. In these older versions, the `datetime` value `2021-12-10 19:58:41.333` would be less accurately converted to the `datetime2(7)` value `2021-12-10 19:58:41.3330000`. If you are on an older version and rely on this behaviour, you need to explicitly convert/cast your `datetime` value to a `datetime2(3)` to avoid a likely breaking change.*

Comment: It's 2016 when the change happened, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15#SQL15. Also https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6405e84131161dcee32f2bafebf716bf

Answer (score 0):

This is actually due to the granularity of `DATETIME`. You will notice there are only 3 possible values for milliseconds in `datetime`: 0,333,or 667. This is because its granularity is one third of the second. When converted to `datetime2`, this expands the decimal digits to correctly represent the fraction.

Comment: I’m getting mixed messages from MSDN. One page on DateTime says its accuracy is “Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds” while another MSDN page says its Accuracy is 0.00333 seconds…could you please elaborate? I will post the links as separate comments…

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The behaviour changed in 2016/2017 (can't recall which off the top of my head) to how a `datetime` to a `datetime2`, in newer versions it is more representative of the accuracy of `datetime`.

Comment: Both are true, @Alexandru . 0.0066666666666 to 3 decimal places is 0.007, not 0.006.

Comment: @Larnu So, one MSDN page deals with the accuracy of the storage of the underlying data of the type while the other MSDN page deals with the way the data as it is presented as an object, yes? Well then, since the page with the underlying data accuracy is at 0.00333s (5 digits of accuracy), why then does the DATETIME2 cast contain 0.3333333s (7 digits of accuracy)?

Comment: `datetime` is accurate to **3** digits not 5, @Alexandru . As for why `datetime2` had 7 digits of accuracy, that's because you didn't define the precision, and so you got the default, and maximum (7).

Comment: @Larnu Not so. It says DATETIME is stored to an accuracy of 0.00333s which at max has 5 decimal places. It says its rounded to 3 when retrieved. So why does DATETIME2 have 7 decimal places for this cast?

Comment: Because you asked for 7 digits @Alexandru ... By your omission of an accuracy.

Comment: @Alexandru, the the actual datetime accuracy is 1/300 sec (an infinitely repeating decimal of 0.0033333333333333333333333333333333333333333....) there wasn't enough room on the doc page to list the actual value in decimal form :-)

Comment: @DanGuzman I really wish they would just put 1/300 there

Comment: Dan is correct. fraction is in 1/300s of a second. This is also evident with the following selects: `SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.003')) * 86400` which yields 0.00333333333333333, not 0.003, and `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(FLOAT, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.003')) * 300)`, which yields 00:00:01.000, not 00:00:00.900`.  Both use the conversion datetime to/from float (days and fraction since 1900-01-01).